# In the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress and after installing a plugin (Unlimited Addons for Visual Composer), I get those error :

*In the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WPAlchemy_MetaBox has a deprecated constructor in /home/hhpariskky/www/wp-content/themes/vertical/includes/vafpress/includes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 61
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WPAlchemy_Taxonomy has a deprecated constructor in /home/hhpariskky/www/wp-content/themes/vertical/includes/vp_new/classes/taxonomy.php on line 17
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WPAlchemy_MetaBox1 has a deprecated constructor in /home/hhpariskky/www/wp-content/themes/vertical/includes/vp_new/classes/MetaBox.php on line 62*

Also, I cannot delete any plugin :

*Échec de suppression : Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WPAlchemy_MetaBox has a deprecated constructor in /home/hhpariskky/www/wp-content/themes/vertical/includes/vafpress/includes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php on line 61 Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WPAlchemy_Taxonomy has a deprecated constructor in /home/hhpariskky/www/wp-content/themes/vertical/includes/vp_new/classes/taxonomy.php on line 17 Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WPAlchemy_MetaBox1 has a deprecated constructor in /home/hhpariskky/www/wp-content/themes/vertical/includes/vp_new/classes/MetaBox.php on line 62 {"success":true,"data":{"delete":"plugin","slug":"hello-dolly","plugin":"hello.php","pluginName":"Hello Dolly"}}*

Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

PHP 7 [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php) classes with old, PHP 4 style constructors:

```
class foo {
    function foo() {
        echo 'I am the constructor';
    }
}
```

should now be:

```
class foo {
    function __construct() {
        echo 'I am the constructor';
    }
}
```

The plugin you're using may have an updated version. If it's no longer getting updates, it may be up to you to adjust it.